# An urn contains n balls numbered $2^i,i=0,\dots,n-1$. Select two w/o replacement -- what is the EV of the sum of 2 balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Problem**

An urn contains n balls numbered 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^(n-1) where n > 1. If a person selects 2 balls without replacement, what is the expected value of the sum of the two balls?

**Solution**

I have solved the case where you select 2 balls with replacement and got the answer: (2/n)(2^n - 1) (*I took the sum of 2^(i-1) from i to n and multiplied it by the probability 1/n and 2 for the two balls*). I am having difficulty with this version of the problem (no replacement).

For the first ball, the EV will simply be (1/n)(2^n - 1). However, what about the second ball? You could draw the lowest  valued ball (1) -- wouldn't that effect the 2nd ball's EV?

Looking for guidance/tips, thanks.

Comment: Balls (or $2$ balls) have no expected value. In a suitable context numbers on balls have an expected value. Further I expect you are after the expectation of the sum of numbers on the two balls. That is not posed clear enough in your question.

Comment: Yep sorry for the lack of clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $B_1$ denote the number on the first ball and $B_2$ the number on the second ball.

Then in both cases (with and without replacement) $B_1$ and $B_2$ have equal distribution so that $\mathbb EB_1=\mathbb EB_2$ hence by linearity of expectation: $$\mathbb E(B_1+B_2)=\mathbb EB_1+\mathbb EB_2=2\mathbb EB_1$$

The difference between the cases is that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are independent by replacement and are not independent in the other case.

Comment: Thank you. So the EV of the sum of two balls is the same with or without replacement?

Comment: Yes it is. You are welcome.

Comment: One last thing (sorry) -- is the equation for the EV of the second ball " (1/n)(2^n - 1)"? In which case I would have 2*((1/n)(2^n - 1)) which is the same result as the case with replacements.

Comment: Also that is correct.

Comment: @McSpeenies Replacement changes the distribution of $B_1+B_2$, but it doesn't change the expectation.

Comment: Thank you both!